# Produce a correctly sized error.jpg image if requested image does not exist in php

Tags: php, image, error-handling

An illegal request is made for image=90273497823 when the source doesn't
exist, you should return a correctly sized placeholder image in its stead.

An example might be:

```
<img src="resources/image.php?id=95648633&amp;x=160&amp;y=120&amp;color=1"  alt="kitty"/>
```

Instead of allowing the webpage to directly pull images from my server, I call the script image.php to service this request, and to handle exceptions if needed. The script works for all images that exist, but for the non existent images the script fails to load the error.jpg image that I have; Leading me to believe my error handling is incorrect.

What I expect my script to do is check whether the file exists, and if not replace with the correctly sized(the same size request of the non-existent image) error.jpg

My script as follows.

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpg');//override the return type
                              //so browser expects image not file
$id=$_GET['id'];//get file name
$new_width=$_GET['x'];//get width
$new_height=$_GET['y'];//get heigth
$color=$_GET['color'];//get colored version type
$filename=$id;//file id is set as file name
$filename.=".jpg";//append .jpg onto end of file name




// create a jpeg from the id get its size
$im=imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// get the size of the image
list($src_w, $src_h, $type, $attr)=getimagesize($filename);


/*
  Exception handling for when an image is requested and the file dosent exist
  in the current file system or directory. Returns file "error.jpg" correctly
  sized in the place of the  requested null file.
*/
if(!file_exists($filename))//(file_exists($filename) == false)
//(!file_exists($filename))
  {


    imagedestroy($im);//why do I have to destroy it, why cant I write over it?
    $im=imagecreatefromjpeg("error.jpg");
    list($src_w, $src_h, $type, $attr)=getimagesize($im);

  }

/*
  this function will resize the image into a temporary image
  and then copy the image back to $im
*/
if($new_width != '' && $new_height != '')

  {
     //MAKE A TEMP IMAGE TO COPY FROM
     $imTemp=imagecreate($new_width, $new_height);
     imagecopyresized($imTemp, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $src_w,
                     $src_h);
     imagedestroy($im);//free up memory space

     //COPY THE TEMP IMAGE OVER TO $im
     $im=imagecreate($new_width, $new_height);
     imagecopy($im, $imTemp, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height);
     imagedestroy($imTemp);//free up memory space
  }

/*
  If the image being requested has color = 0, then we return a grayscale image,
  but if the image is already grayscale
*/
if($color == 0)
  {
     imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
  }

//What do we do if color = 0, but they want a colorized version of it???

imagejpeg($im);//output the image to the browser
imagedestroy($im);//free up memory space
?>
```

Comment: This needs basic debugging first. And you are not doing any error checks, add them. Then tell us exactly which error and warnings appear and at which line. I assume it's already up at the top 10 lines or so.

Answer (score 0):

[getimagesize](http://php.net/getimagesize) takes a filename, not an image resource handle. That might one place you are going wrong.